# CSS3 pie shadow issue

Tags: jquery, css, css3pie

I'm using CSS3 Pie to create box shadows and rounded corners in IE.  I have a background container with a box shadow and then another div that sits on top of the first.  What happens is, the box shadow borders around all of the boxes as if it were one container instead of outlining both all the way. It looks fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, the problem is just in IE.

The page that's having the issue is [here](http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Patients_Visitors/pcs/rehabilitationservices/mock/standards.aspx).

And here's the code, it's pretty straightforward:

```
<div id="standards_backing" 
class="gradient_1 gradient_2 gradient_3 gradient_4 gradient_5 gradient_6" 
style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 4px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 4px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 4px;
background: fbfbfb;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(fbfbfb), to(f4f4f5));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: -o-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
behavior: url(pie.htc);">


<div id="standards_container_total">

<div 
class="standard_containers gradient_1 gradient_2 gradient_3 gradient_4 gradient_5  
gradient_6" 
style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 4px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 4px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 4px;
background: fbfbfb;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(fbfbfb), to(f4f4f5));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: -o-linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
background: linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(fbfbfb, f4f4f5);
behavior: url(pie.htc);">

</div></div></div>




var standards_backing = {
    "width": "690px",
    "margin-left": "17px",
    "padding-top": "35px",
    "padding-bottom": "30px"
};
var standards_container_total = {
    "width": "2968px",
    "margin-left": "-26px",
    "margin-top": "100px",
    "position": "relative"
};
var standard_containers = {
    "width": "341px",
    "margin-top": "-25px",
    "margin-left": "15px",
    "margin-right": "15px",
    "padding-top": "15px",
    "padding-bottom": "25px",
    "float": "left",
    "display": "inline-block"
};


$("#standards_backing").css(standards_backing);
$("#standards_container_total").css(standards_container_total);
$(".standard_containers").css(standard_containers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a background color on the panels while also setting `overflow: hidden;` to keep the background from flowing over the rounded corners.

Comment: hmmm, didn't seem to change anything, just changed it and it looks the same, strange issue